# Who is the weak* sequential closure of the set of finitely supported measures on the integers?

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$, the sequential closure of $Y$ is the set of elements in $X$ that are limit of **sequences** belonging to $Y$.

Let $\mathcal M_{\text{fin}}(\mathbb Z)$ be the set of finitely supported probability measures on $\mathbb Z$. The general question is: who is the weak* sequential closure of $\mathcal M_{\text{fin}}(\mathbb Z)$? This set should be different from the set of all finitely additive probability measures on $\mathbb Z$, since $L^\infty(\mathbb Z)$ is not separable.

I'm actually interested in a more specific question: does this closure contain at least one (all??) translation invariant finitely additive probability measure?

Thanks in advance,

Valerio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The finitely support probability measures on $\mathbb Z$ are all members of $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$.  So we could ask a slightly more general question:

> What is the sequential closure of (the probability measures in) $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)^*$?

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ which converges weak$^*$ in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)^*$, then $f(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence for all $f\in \ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$.  Now, $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ is weakly sequentially complete (*) and so there is $a\in\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ with $f(a_n) \rightarrow f(a)$ for each $f\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$.  In other words, the weak$^*$ limit of $(a_n)$ actually lives in $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$.  So the answer is "no" in a strong sense.

(*) All preduals of a von Neumann algebra are weakly sequentially complete (see Takesaki I, Chapter III, Corollary 5.2).  There is presumably an easy proof for $\ell^1$, but I don't know a reference off the top of my head.

**Edit:** The following is prompted by Bill Johnson's comment (and reveals nothing so much as my own ignorance!)  A Banach space $E$ is said to have the Schur Property if weakly convergent sequences are norm convergent-- Schur originally showed that $\ell^1$ has the Schur Property.  We say that $E$ is weakly sequentially complete (WSC) if whenever $(x_n)$ is weakly Cauchy (meaning that for each $f\in E^*$, the scalar sequence $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy) then $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent.  The Schur property implies WSC-- if $(x_n)$ is weakly Cauchy, then for any increasing sequences $(n_k)$ and $(m_k)$, the sequence $(x_{n_k} - x_{m_k})_k$ is weakly-null, hence norm-null, and hence $(x_n)$ is norm Cauchy.  You can find all this in Section 2.3 of Albiac and Kalton's book.  For a general measure $\mu$, the space $L^1(\mu)$ is WSC, but doesn't necessarily have the Schur property-- see Section 5.2 of this book.

Comment: In fact, $\ell_1$ has the Schur property.  Every weakly Cauchy sequence is norm convergent.  You can find this in many basic texts on Banach space theory.

Comment: @Bill-- Yes, I should have added that.  What worried me is that e.g. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property) seems to want that we already know $(a_n)$ converges weakly to $a\in \ell^1$ (to then conclude actual norm convergence).  Maybe I shouldn't use Wikipedia...

Comment: You can find the proof (of the stronger result Bill alludes to) in e.g. http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&lpg=PA252&dq=schur%20property&pg=PA252#v=onepage&q=schur%20property&f=false  or  http://books.google.com/books?id=fD-GeCsqoqkC&lpg=PA220&dq=schur%20property&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=schur%20property&f=false  Neither argument is particularly hard.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  I'd like to know if there is a more elementary answer to it.  Here's a candidate start of an answer:

Converging weak* in $l^\infty({\mathbb Z})^*$ implies in particular that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence for all $n$.  Let me use the notation $f(a_n)$ to denote the dual pairing between $f \in l^\infty$ and $a_n \in l^1$.  From the existence of a weak limit, we see there is a pointwise limit $a = (a_k)$, and hence $f(a_n) \to f(a)$ for all compactly supported $f$.  To see that $a$ is in $l^1$, observe that we have the bound $|f(a_n)| \leq C$ for all $||f||_{l^\infty} \leq 1$ and all $n$ because $f(a_n) \to A[f]$ for some bounded, linear functional $A \in (l^\infty)^*$.  With this estimate in hand, we can conclude that $f(a_n) \to f(a)$ for all $||f||_{l^\infty} \leq 1$ which vanish at infinity, and therefore $|f(a)| \leq C$ for all such $f$.  It then follows that $a \in l^1$ by just the Lebesgue-theoretic definition of an infinite sum  of positive numbers as a supremum of finite sums (just choose the $f$ correctly).

What this argument has not shown is that $f(a_n) \to f(a)$ for all $f$ in $l^\infty$.  It seems like the only thing that could have gone wrong is if somehow the mass of $|a_n - a|$ could have gone off towards infinity in ${\mathbb Z}$.  But if this were the case, it seems like you could cook up an $f \in l^\infty$ so that $f(a_n)$ oscillates, which would contradict the weak convergence of the sequence.

Comment: @Phil:  Basically you are starting the proof that $\ell_1$ has the Schur property.  If $f_n$ is weakly Cauchy in $\ell_1$ then it weak`$^*$` converges (`$\ell_1=\co_0^*$`) converges to, say,  $f$ (which, since $f_n$ must be bounded, is the same as saying that $f_n$ converges coordinatewise to $f$). Subtract off $f$ from each $f_n$ to assume WLOG that $f=0$.  If the new $f_n$ does not converge in norm to zero, use a gliding hump argument to get a subsequence with bid disjoint pieces.  So far  $\ell_1$ could have been any of the familiar  sequence spaces. Now use that your space is $\ell_1$.